# Generate temporary login in php / mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to know if it's possible in php/mysql to generate some random and temporary access link or login in order to access to a website. Like the sharable link of discord for example. 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?